# Illegal nesting: Nothing may be nested beneath import directives

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Im working with rails 4.2 and bootstrap-sass -> 3.2.0 gem. I converted css into sass and added to application.css.sass file.

Im getting `Illegal nesting: Nothing may be nested beneath import directives.`

```
@import "bootstrap"

  height: 5px
  border-top: 0
  background: #c4e17f
  border-radius: 5px
```

any ideas as to why I'm encourtering this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code sample I see that you have not associated the style to any class or id.

It can look like

```
.container
  height: 5px       
  border-top: 0
  background: #c4e17f
  border-radius: 5px
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

Don't indent you styles, create a class or put it in an html tag.

Example:

```
@import "bootstrap"

body {
    height: 5px
    border-top: 0
    background: #c4e17f
    border-radius: 5px
}
```

OR

```
@import "bootstrap"

body
  height: 5px
  border-top: 0
  background: #c4e17f
  border-radius: 5px
```